# Is there a possibility to send an email via Gmail but without intents?

Tags: android, email, gmail

I want to send an email via Gmail but without using intents, is it possible with some Google features?

Comment: I don't think you could do that, even if there is any helper method out there, it still might be use Intent without you knowing it

Comment: have you ever tried to send it via Google Spreadsheets? It is very powerful tool

Comment: I don't think its possible . Cause this will violate security policy in some way .Here a [tutorial](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Send-Mail-in-Android-without-Using-Intent)  i found . I have no idea but you can have a look .Thx'

Comment: What makes you think that all your users use Gmail?

Comment: the other way is using API.. where is you send the text to the api and server do all the work